# Trying to create call option payoff profile but keep getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, yfinance

I am trying to create a payoff profile in Python but keep getting:

```
"ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')"
```

when I declare the variable **callPayoff**. Here is my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
tickers = input("Enter Ticker in CAPS: ")
print (tickers)

intraData = yf.download(tickers = tickers, period = '7d', interval = '1m')

curPrice = intraData.iloc[-1, intraData.columns.get_loc("Close")]
strikePrice = input("What is your Strike Price?: ")

lowerbound = curPrice * 0.8
upperbound = curPrice * 1.2

curPrice_PP = np.arange(lowerbound, upperbound, 0.01)

#use a lambda for a call payoff function:
callPayoff = lambda curPrice, strikePrice: np.maximum(curPrice_PP - strikePrice, 0)

#use a lambda for a put payoff function
putPayoff = lambda curPrice, strikePrice: np.maximum(strikePrice - curPrice_PP, 0)

#plot the call payoff
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Call Option Payoff at Expiration')
plt.xlabel("Underlying stock price")
plt.ylabel("Price of Option at Expiration")
plt.plot(curPrice_PP, callPayoff(curPrice_PP, strikePrice))
```

Comment: Are the variable names correct in the lambda? Do you mean `callPayoff = lambda curPrice, strikePrice: np.maximum(curPrice - strikePrice, 0)` Maybe also take care when reusing variable names.

Comment: You can't subtract strings from strings!.  `U32` means that the array(s) in question contain strings, not numbers.

Comment: When asking about an error like this, show the **full** error message including traceback.  Don't summarize it and leave us guessing as to where it occurs.  You might even be able to deduce something about the error by reading the traceback yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Does this simpler example give you ideas of where and why your error occurs?

```
In [261]: np.arange(10)-'astromg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-261-b7b809d0f016>", line 1, in <module>
    np.arange(10)-'astromg'
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')
```

Comment: This isn’t really an answer. Agreed that the OPs problems probably stem in part from strikePrice not necessarily being a float, but I think the mixing of variable names in the lambda isn’t helping either.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj stated, you cannot subtract strings! When I prompted the user to input a strike price, it saved the input as a string, I simply changed this to:

```
strikePrice = int(input("What is your Strike Price?: "))
```

Comment: Are your strikes always integers? If not, perhaps use float() instead.